# Django-model: Save computed value in a model field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to save the django model with computed field so that I can apply search on that.

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    x = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    z = models.CharField(max_length=16)

    # I want a field like below and also saves in databse
    # computed =  computed()

    def computed(self):
        result = self.x + self.y
        return result
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We should override save() method.

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    x = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    z = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    computed =  models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def get_computed(self):
        result = self.x + self.y
        return result

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.computed = self.get_computed()
        super(TestModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: To make it shorter, you could simply add self.x+self.y in your save method itself, rather than putting it in separate method.

Answer (score 25):

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    x = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    z = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    computed = models.CharField(max_length=32, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.computed = self.x + self.y
        super(TestModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#editable) is what `editable` option does. [More](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods).

Comment: Even overriding save method for Model is a viable option as stated above.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you must have your 'computed' field defined in your TestModel. Then when you are creating a new TestModel record, you can compute x + y during record creation and save it.

```
TestModel.objects.create(x=x_value, y=y_value, computed=(x_value + y_value))
```

This should do it.

Comment: While this works in principle, using `save()` is better because there is only one part of the code where the value is computed. If `create()` is called from multiple parts of the code, each of them need to compute the value.